# How do I export Readonly variables with mod_perl?

Tags: perl, readonly, mod-perl, exporter

I'm trying to make it easier to follow some [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735/) by creating a `Constants` module that exports several of the scalars used throughout the book.  One in particular, `$EMPTY_STRING`, I can use in just about every Perl script I write.  What I'd like is to automatically export these scalars so I can use them without defining them explicitly in each script.

```
#!perl
package Example::Constants;

use Exporter qw( import );
use Readonly;

Readonly my $EMPTY_STRING => q{};
our @EXPORT = qw( $EMPTY_STRING );
```

An example usage:

```
#!perl
use Example::Constants;
print $EMPTY_STRING . 'foo' . $EMPTY_STRING;
```

Using the above code produces an error:

```
Global symbol "$EMPTY_STRING" requires explicit package name
```

If I change the `Readonly` declaration to:

```
Readonly our $EMPTY_STRING => q{}; # 'our' instead of 'my'
```

The error becomes:

```
Attempt to reassign a readonly scalar
```

Is this just not possible with mod_perl?

Answer (score 4):

You had 4 problems:

1. You weren't including the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas
2. It is better to include exporter through the `base` pragma (since it sets `@ISA` for you)
3. Only package variables (i.e. `our` variables) can be exported
4. Modules must end with a true value

Here is the corrected module.

```
package Example::Constants;

use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Exporter';
use Readonly;

Readonly our $EMPTY_STRING => q{};
our @EXPORT = qw( $EMPTY_STRING );

1;
```

Hmm, I missed the bit about attempting to assign to a readonly, it sounds like the module is getting loaded more than once.  I believe mod_perl has a [mechanism](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/config.html#PerlModule_and_PerlRequire_Directives) for loading modules separate from the scripts themselves.  This loading happens only once, so you should be using it.

Comment: I'm already doing 1, 3 and 4, I just left them out of the example for brevity.  Also, use Exporter qw( import ) is the preferred method, not use base qw( Exporter ).  Adding the module to PerlRequire still produces the error, one for each http process started.

Comment: Also, did you remove "use Example::Constants;" from your script?

Comment: This works for me as-is!
Perhaps you could include the code using it from the question as well, for completeness:

use Example::Constants;
print $EMPTY_STRING . 'foo' . $EMPTY_STRING;

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of the Readonly module.  The next version of Readonly will provide support for mod_perl, specifically because of this problem.

I know this doesn't solve your problem *now*, but... well, I'm working on it :-)

-- Eric

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.  If it matters, I am also using the Readonly::XS module.

Comment: Well Eric, it's been a year.  Any progress with this? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a mod_perl instance handy to test with, so I can't test these suggestions.  I hope they pan out.

Try using `Scalar::Util::readonly` to check if the variable has already been marked read only.

```
#!perl
package Example::Constants;

use Exporter qw( import );
use Readonly;
use Scalar::Util qw(readonly);

our $EMPTY_STRING;
our @EXPORT = qw( $EMPTY_STRING );

if ( !readonly( $EMPTY_STRING ) ) {
    Readonly $EMPTY_STRING => q{};
}
```

You could also try `use vars`:

```
#!perl
package Example::Constants;

use Exporter qw( import );
use Readonly;
use vars qw( $EMPTY_STRING );

Readonly $EMPTY_STRING => q{};
our @EXPORT = qw( $EMPTY_STRING );
```

You could also use a typeglob constant:

```
#!perl
package Example::Constants;

use Exporter qw( import );
use Readonly;

our $EMPTY_STRING;
*EMPTY_STRING = \q{};
our @EXPORT = qw( $EMPTY_STRING );
```

Using a typeglob constant seems perfect, since the big limitation of the technique (it requires a package global) is not an issue here.